# Php artisan migrate doesn't work on docker container

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5

**SOLUTION**: docker inspect | grep IP get the postgres running container's ip and update your env DB_HOST and DB_PORT with container's ip and port respectively.

**UPDATE**: Writing postgres to DB_HOST is best practice due to ip address may change.

---

I've been searching for a day to connect database from docker container to my Laravel app, but whatever I've tried, even though I can connect it via Postico I cannot migrate my database. I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
>     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>     TCP/IP connections on port 3306?

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base

RUN apk add postgresql postgresql-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN apk add zlib-dev git zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction

ENV PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:./vendor/bin:${PATH}"
```

**My docker-compose file:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11.10-alpine
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/vendor
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://foodorder@postgres/foodorder
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: foodorder
      POSTGRES_DB: foodorder
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123123
    ports:
      - 3306:5432
```

**My env file:**

```
DB_CONNECTION = "pgsql"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_HOST="localhost"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_SCHEMA="foodorder"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_DATABASE="foodorder"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_PORT="3306"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_USERNAME="foodorder"
DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_PASSWORD="123123"
```

And finally, in my **database.php**,

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => env('DATABASE_CONNECTIONS_MASTER_PGSQL_SCHEMA'),
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the database user has access on both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. It sounds like you're trying to connect to `localhost` but access has only been granted for `127.0.0.1`, or vice versa.

Comment: Now, the error message changed as --> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 3306?

Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member
 of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------
----
 foodorder | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}